# Unclear how the word “verantwortet” is used in a sentence

Tags: sentence-structure, past-participle, austrian

In DWDS the following sentence appears under the entry for [das Hohnlachen](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Hohnlachen).

> Aber wenn ich die sogenannten modernen Tanzpartner der modernen
> Tänzerinnen sehe, habe ich nur ein verantwortetes Hohnlachen!

If the word “*verantwortet*” means to be “responsible for”, does the writer want to say that the current situation of modern dance partners is responsible for his scornful laughter?  I am not sure how this past participle is being used.

**EDIT:**

The above sentence appears in an extract of [Altenberg, Peter: Mein Lebensabend](http://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/Altenberg,+Peter/Autobiographisches/Mein+Lebensabend/Im+60.+Lebensjahre) and a bit more detail around the sentence is as follows:

> Was kann dieses erlösende regenerierende Schlafmittel für meinen
> melancholischen Irrsinn?!? Ich empfehle es euch dringendst,
> Schlaflose, ein Likörglas! Nach fünf Monaten Zimmerkerker
> schrecklichster Art, im April Erlösung, vollständige, nein, mehr als
> vollständige Regeneration, eine neue Jugend-Elastizität, so daß ich
> Tanzpartner der Grete Wiesenthal werden will im Oktober bei
> »Ronacher«. Ich werde am 9. März 1919 60 Jahre alt. Aber wenn ich die
> sogenannten modernen Tanzpartner der modernen Tänzerinnen sehe, habe
> ich nur ein verantwortetes Hohnlachen! Vor allem keinerlei Anmut,
> männlich-frauenhaft eben zugleich muß man sich biegen können!

Comment: There seems to be only one source for "verantwortetes Hohnlachen" which sounds strange. I'm not sure if this is a mistake or intentional. The combination doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @Bodo I have added further details around the text.  Hope this helps.

Comment: This is exactly the only source I found, and to me as a native speaker the wording "verantwortetes Hohnlachen" doesn't make sense.

Comment: Two remarks: Altenberg was from Austria, so it might be a special Austrian phrase. It seems clear, however, that the meaning of *verantwortet* is probably close to *to offer as response (=Antwort)".

Comment: That excerpt is full of artistic freedom and word plays. Most native speakers will struggle with it. It requires the kind of in-depth literary analysis that most of us considered a special kind of torture when we were still students. The protagonist states in the beginning that they are kind of crazy (in fact, apparently a drunkard) and the text is supposed to reflect that.

Comment: @SatishVasan:
It can be shown that the writer (Altenberg) consistently used "verantworten" as a synonym of "rechtfertigen" (see [my answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/65655)). Therefore, I suggest "a *justified* scornful laugh".
Here, "verantwortet" does carry the connotation of "answer" or "response", but over and above that, it conveys the *reason* (or a rationalization) for his response (laughter).

Comment: @Roland and others:
Seeing as the author wrote in the age of expressionism, he was not alone in (over-)using artistic freedoms, creative grammar, and expressive excesses, which you rightly point to.
Still, this particular word choice allows for a rational (lexical) explanation. I wouldn't write it off as just the protagonist's madness. In fact, it is even supposed to express his *rational* justification of his behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Peter Altenberg speaks in this text from an event in the year 1918 in past tense:

> Im Jahre 1918 glitt ich von der schlecht von Seife abgeschwabten Steinstiege vor meiner Hoteltüre mit meinen glatten Holzsandalen, nachts 1/2 12 Uhr, nach rückwärts aus, brach die beiden Handwurzel-Knochen.

But Altenberg died of pneumonia on 9<sup>th</sup> of January 1919. This means, this text most likely was written in late 1918.

Altenberg was known as a scrounger (although he was rich), he was antisemitic, he was pedophile and he was an alcoholic (he drunk up to 40 bottles of beer per day) who very often had to spend time in psychiatric hospitals in the last 10 years of his life. So, we have two facts:

1. The text is more than 100 years old, and German has changed noticeable since then.
2. Although Altenberg was a famous *Kaffeehausliterat* (Viennese coffee house writer), he was no longer in full possession of his mental powers at the end of his life.

I believe, that both facts together will result in a very specific variation of individual interpretation of German language, that can not be compared to modern standard German.

The quoted sentence is wrong in standard German, but it might be correct in Altenbergs personal variation of German.

Comment: *"... The text is more than 100 years old ..."* is the one and only interesting fact here. All the rest has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @Olafant I think it is interesting and relevant to know that he probably did not have an absolutely clear mind when he wrote this.

Comment: @Olafant: The question was about a specific text written by a specific author. You can only answer this kind of questions when you dive into the authors mind and try to understand the world he lived in. In [the text from which the quoted fragment was taken](http://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/Altenberg,+Peter/Autobiographisches/Mein+Lebensabend/Im+60.+Lebensjahre) you hardly will find any grammatical correct sentence. This was not the common language of 1918. This was Peter Altenbergs language. To understand why he used such a strange language, it helps to know, that he was a sick man.

Comment: He was antisemitic (and btw. jewish), he was pedophile and he was an alcoholic (like Hemingway, Bukowski ...?) doesn't say anything about him being able or not able to write a proper sentence. Neither does the fact that he spend time in psychiatric hospitals. Let me say it really clear: this answer is nothing but opinon and boulevard style. *Don't think about it, the guy was just crazy?*

Comment: up to 40 bottles 0,3, 0,5, or 1,0 liter!? This is important, for science.

Answer (score 7):

Hubert Schölnast has explained why the weird phrase "verantwortetes Hohnlachen" should be regarded as an idiosyncrasy of the author.

Anyway, the verb *veranworten* also has another connotation than  "responsible for". This may be outdated nowadays, but perhaps it was not when the author wrote his text (or the author had a fondness for old-fashioned expressions).

The [Deutsches Wörterbuch von Jacob Grimm und Wilhelm Grimm](https://woerterbuchnetz.de/?sigle=DWB#0) says that it can also mean *beantworten*. Quotation:

**verantworten**, *verb. respondere, probare. ahd. nicht nachgewiesen, mhd.* verantwurten, -worten, -wirten, -werten Lexer 3, 69; *nhd.* verantwurten, verantworten, *mnd.* verantworden, verantwerden, *holl.* verantwoorden. *über mischung der formen* antwort (*responsum*) *und* antwert (*praesentia*) *siehe theil* 1, 509.

1. *intransitiv:* ...
2. *transitiv: überall tritt gegenüber dem simplex, wenn auch die bedeutung sich deckt, ein gegensatz in der construction hervor, indem bei* verantworten *die zu beantwortende (verantwortende) sache im accusativ beigefügt wird.*
   a) *beantworten: mhd.* eʒ wolt die stat wiʒʒen, ob er ir friund oder find wolte sin. daʒ verantwort der marschalk also und sprach: er künd der pottschaft alspald nit antwurten, er wölt ritter und knecht raut darum haben, wie er daʒ verantwurt. *städtechron.* 4, 105, 18; *nhd. noch bei Stieler* 2581 verantworten *id quod* beantworten; Maaler, Steinbach *und* Frisch *kennen das wort nicht in dieser bedeutung*; do sprach Xanthus zuo den gertnern: es ist unziemlich, daʒ ein söllicher maister .. alle rätterschen verantwurte in den garten. aber myn knab ist wiszend genuog, sölliche frag ze verantwürten.   /Bd. 25, Sp. 80/ Steinhöwel Esop 49 Öst.; nun wolan: also hast du die ersten frag verantwurt, was da sei der lon des spinnens. Keisersberg *spinnerin* (*Straszburg* 1511) c 2b; noch steet ausz zu verantwurten, was der lon jrs spinnens sei. od; denn solcher bücher hab ich viel mit schweigen verantwortet und als ein ganzpfeiffen lassen für uber rauschen. Luther 6, 112a; das Heintze weiter den churfürsten ... auffrührisch schilt, ist auch gleicher gestalt zu verantworten, nemlich das er sich selbs in die backen hauwet und leuget. *Hans Worst* 43 *neudruck*; ich hab euer schrift, so nu längst mir zukomen, bisher nicht verantwurt, *briefe* 4, 218; nachdem wir die sprüche, so die wiedersacher aus der schrift angezogen, recht ausgelegt und verantwort haben. Melanchthon *corp. doctr. Christ.* (1560) 220; mit stillschweigen verantwort man vil. Frank *sprichw.* 165 *Latendorf*; liesen mir ein grausam schreiben durch einen herold zukommen .. (*ich*) solte .. mich der werbung des kriegsvolcks abthon, aber ich verantwortet daselbig mit solcher bescheidenheit, dasz ich nicht gesinnet wäre wider ihr maj. zu kriegen. Schärtlin *lebensb.* (1777) 86; ach wer biszweilen verhören könte und verantwort nicht alles und liesz S. Peters und Rolands schwerd in der scheiden stecken. Schuppius 832; und ein bei dem trunck geredetes wort mit degen und pistol verantworten wil. 655;

   mit schweigen man veranttwort vil,
   schaden entpfoht, wer schwätzen wil.
   Brant narrensch. (19) 25;

   weil ich auff tausent seiner frag
   nicht eine verantworten mag.
   H. Sachs 3, 1, 249 (11, 410, 35 Keller)

   *in der heutigen sprache ist* verantworten *in dieser bedeutung vollständig durch das in älterer zeit seltnere, aber doch vorkommende beantworten* (*theil* 1, 1206) *verdrängt.*

The meaning of Altenberg's sentence should therefore be

> Aber wenn ich die sogenannten modernen Tanzpartner der modernen Tänzerinnen sehe, habe ich als Antwort nur ein Hohnlachen!

> Aber wenn ich die sogenannten modernen Tanzpartner der modernen Tänzerinnen sehe, habe ich nur ein beantwortendes Hohnlachen!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. +1

Comment: While I upvoted, I guess this is not digestable for non-native speakers. I also fail to find the strikingly similar use in the examples, which could be boldfaced, if present. Finally *verantwortet* seems passive participle, while the context requires something more similar to a *gerund*.

Comment: @guidot I agree with the point concerning the syntax of "verantwortet". I believe my new answer points to a solution.

Answer (score 3):

### "Verantwortet" as "gerechtfertigt" or "berechtigt"

None of the comments or answers so far (even [PaulFrost's interesting deep dive into the DWB](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/63422)) has attempted to clarify what meaning *the author*, Peter Altenberg, *usually* attached to the term "verantworten".
This can be done by way a *corpus search*: the 1919 collection from which OP quoted, *Mein Lebensabend*, is entirely [digitized](http://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/Altenberg,+Peter/Autobiographisches/Mein+Lebensabend).

This provides us with the following answer:

Altenberg habitually uses *verantwortet* as a synonym for *berechtigt* or *gerechtfertigt*.

Therefore, in

> (1) Aber wenn ich die sogenannten modernen Tanzpartner der modernen Tänzerinnen sehe, habe ich nur ein verantwortetes Hohnlachen!

the expression almost certainly means "a **justified** scornful laugh"; the passage can be rendered as

> (1) Aber wenn ich die sogenannten modernen Tanzpartner der modernen Tänzerinnen sehe, habe ich nur ein **berechtigtes** Hohnlachen!

There are several instances of such usage of "verantworten" in *Mein Lebensabend* (see below); but first I point to the DWB and the sub-entry of "verantworten" that I deem most relevant.
(This issue of the DWB – Bd. XII, I, Lieferung 1: V-VERDAMMEN – was published in 1886.)

### The relevant DWB entry

The relevant sense of "verantworten" is to be found right after the passage by which
PaulFrost  justified his suggestion to read *verantworten* as *antworten*.
In fact, this passage describes a shift in meaning, starting from "antworten":

> b) Leicht schließt die Antwort auf eine Frage eine Rechtfertigung, Entschuldigung in sich. Die Bedeutung mag, wie bei *antworten* (Theil 1, 510), dem Rechtsleben entstammen, wo die Klage als Frage aufgefaßt wurde. **So heißt *verantworten* zunächst vor Gericht vertheidigen, dann überhaupt rechtfertigen, vertheidigen**[.]
> ([DWB s.v. verantworten](http://www.woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/verantworten), edited for readability.)

Examples:  "ich kann verantworten, was ich sage" (Tieck);  "... aber ich wills verantworten" (Schiller).

This **transitive** use of verantworten means "(etw.) rechtfertigen, verteidigen" – "to justify, defend sth.". Its focus is on the thing (behavior, claim) that is to be justified.

From this is further derived the reflexive usage "*sich* verantworten" (no. 4. in DWB), which (I would argue) is more familiar to a modern ear - as in "sich vor Gericht verantworten" = "to defend *oneself* in court".

Note that, syntactically speaking, 2.b. is a *transitive* form, and thus fits the Altenberg quote better than the *intransitive* form equivalent to "(be)antworten" (DWB 2.a. [as relayed by PaulFrost](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/63422)).

Also, semantically speaking,"verantworten" in the former interpretation as "(be)antworten" denotes (a) a *reaction to* something else, or possibly *someone else's* actions; (b) which could very well be an *irrational* knee-jerk reaction. On the other hand, (a) the most typical object of "verantworten" as "rechtfertigen" would be *my own* behavior or claims, and (b) it expressed an alleged *reason* why these are *justified*.

The examples from Altenberg's writings fit the latter interpretation as "rechtfertigen" very well –
which is no wonder, given the egotistical slant of his writing – the  constant focus on his own *Gedankenwelt*.

### Examples from Altenberg

By digging into *Mein Lebensabend*, one finds two instances of "verantworten" as transitive verb (2-3) and two more instances of the *past participle* "verantwortet" (4-5). Luckily, these are all more straightforward than the ‘Hohnlachen’ passage the OP came upon (1).

While examples (2-4) are all best rendered as *rechtfertigen*, example (5) is the most interesting, since it is an *adjectival* use of the past participle – just like the one in (1) –
and can be translated as *berechtigt* or *gerechtfertigt*.

### Finite transitive verb

**(2) From ["Wie ich Übersetzer wurde"](http://www.zeno.org/nid/20004408144):**

> (2) Als ich es dann in meinem Zimmer wieder durchlas, **konnte ich innerlich die etwas übertriebene Art, mich auszudrücken, verantworten**. Ja, uns, uns Besiegten der Seele ist es aufgebürdet, zu tragen die wirkliche Last des Daseins! Und wir tragen!

> ...I could *justify (defend)* unto myself my earlier, rather dramatic tone.

**(3) From ["Der 13. Dezember 1918, 5 Uhr morgens"](http://www.zeno.org/nid/20004411927):**

> (3) Habt Ihr keinen Respekt vor Euch ganz fremden, nur leider scheinbar gleichen, Welten?!? **Könnt Ihr Eure Ratschläge verantworten?!** Kennt Ihr Euch in diesem Labyrinthe »der Anderen« wirklich aus?!?

i.e. (loosely rendered) "How would you *justify* the advice you give, since you can never understand the other person's experience?"

Now to the two instances of the past participle "verantwortet", which also fit this pattern.

### Past participle

**(4) From ["Frankreich"](http://www.zeno.org/nid/20004410343):**

> (4) Die Franzosen sind in kindischer Überreiztheit **zu dem falschen, durch nichts verantworteten Schlusse** gekommen: *Die Deutschen stinken*!

The conclusion is described as wrong – and as "*durch nichts* verantwortet".

Again, the word can be substituted with "gerechtfertigt":

> zu dem falschen, durch nichts **gerechtfertigten** Schlusse

i.e.,  "the wrong conclusion that isn't *justified* by anything"; or "the wrong, completely un*justified* conclusion".

**(5) From ["Mord"](http://www.zeno.org/nid/20004410092):**

> (5) Meine Herren! Tout *comprendre* c'est tout *pardonner*; das ist natürlich eine jener *exaltiert-übertriebenen* Phrasen der Franzosen, des französischen Geistes! Aber sagen wir Gemäßigteren **mit einer gewissen *verantworteten* Gerechtigkeitsliebe**: Alles *Verstehen* heißt wenigstens ein bißchen milde *dadurch werden*, und wenigstens *Etwas* davon verstehen!

Here, Altenberg contrasts a sense of justice that is "verantwortet" and is suitable for "us *moderates*" with – on the other hand – "those *exalted-exaggerated* clichés".
I submit that in this context, too, "verantwortet" can be substituted with "gerechtfertigt" or "berechtigt":

> mit einer gewissen **berechtigten** Gerechtigkeitsliebe

While the clichés are unjustified and illegitimate, Altenberg (the "moderate" replies "with a certain *justifiable/legitimate* sense of justice".

### The original example

Altenberg usually employs the verb "verantworten" as a synonym for "rechtfertigen" and the *past participle* as equivalent to "gerechtfertigt" or "berechtigt". In example (4), he complements the participle with "durch [nichts]"; the usage in (5) is either elliptical or adjectival. The same is the case in the original example (1).

The evidence suggests the following paraphrase of the Hohnlachen-passage:

> Aber wenn ich die sogenannten modernen Tanzpartner der modernen Tänzerinnen sehe, habe ich nur ein **berechtigtes [gerechtfertigtes]** Hohnlachen!

### How common/idiosyncratic?

While the meaning of "verantwortet" in this instance is clear,
I cannot speak to the question of wider interest:
whether this usage is purely idiosyncratic – Altenberg's general style certainly is, as pointed out by @Roland and others –
or whether it might have been somewhat common at some point.
It was hardly universal, and it does sound strange to the modern ear, but might it have been common in Austrian German; in or before the 1910s; possibly in *spoken* language, for which few written records exist...?